# Autoit ControlSetText function does not insert the file path

Tags: selenium, webdriver, autoit

The below solution was posted in response to - "How to automate file upload using Selenium webdriver"

```
var Autoit = new AutoItX3();
const string widowTitle = "File Upload";
Autoit.WinWait(widowTitle, "File &name:", 10);
Autoit.ControlSetText(widowTitle, "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", pathToFile);
Autoit.ControlClick(widowTitle, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]");
Autoit.WinWaitClose(widowTitle, "File &name:", 10);
```

Follow-up question: In the above example, pathToFile does not update the path in the file upload dialog.

I tried using other AutoIt function to update the file path but in vain. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Note: In debug mode the file path is updated correctly and the file is fetched.

Comment: In what browser? What version of the web driver do you have? What version of Selenium do you have? What version of the browser do you have? Is it the same in all browsers?

Comment: It is the same on all browsers. Selenium Webdriver for C#: 2.25.1

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file type the file name to a file input element:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*
import java.util.concurrent.*

driver = new FirefoxDriver()
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
driver.get("http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_FILE.html")
driver.findElementByName("upfile").sendKeys("c:\\temp\\myFile.txt")
driver.findElementByCssSelector("td.content input[type='submit']").click()
```

Don't click file input fields, just use sendKeys, file selection dialog is handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. The solution you suggested works fine in pages where the element is present. I cannot find those elements on my page and am using AutoIt. My problem is related to usage of Autoit.